# How is the expression `+++a` evaluated in the C programming language?

Tags: c, compilation

Consider the following program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 42;
    printf("%d\n", +++a);

    return 0;
}
```

GCC and Clang refuse this program with the error "lvalue required as increment operand". This indicates that these compilers parse `+++a` as `++(+a)`.

Meanwhile, [chibicc](https://github.com/rui314/chibicc) successfully compiles the above program that prints `43`. This indicates that it interprets `+++a` as `+(++a)` (the logic is [implemented in the tokenizer](https://github.com/rui314/chibicc/blob/90d1f7f199cc55b13c7fdb5839d1409806633fdb/tokenize.c#L144)).

The [C standard draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf) contains the following syntax definitions related to `+++a` (unrelated syntax is omitted):

```
unary-expression:
    identifier
    ++ unary-expression
    unary-operator cast-expression

unary-operator: one of
    & * + - ˜ !

cast-expression:
    unary-expression
```

Given the syntax above, `+++a` can either be parsed as

```
++  (         unary-expression          )
    (unary-operator)   (cast-expression )
          +            (unary-expression)
                       (   identifier   )
                               a
```

or

```
(unary-operator)  (  cast-expression   )
      +           (  unary-expression  )
                  ++  (unary-expression)
                      (   identifier   )
                              a
```

So, it seems like `+++a` causes ambiguity during parsing. That is, `+++a` has undefined behavior.

**My question is: is my interpretation correct, or is there any rule that clarifies the result of `+++a` (e.g., the order of syntax rules that a compiler must follow during parsing)?**

Comment: chibicc is incorrect.  This code should give an error.  The C standard is very clear that the token stream for `+++a` is `++`, `+`, `a`, so it's equivalent to `++ + a`, which is a syntax error.  The method used by C to identify tokens is known as "maximal munch".

Comment: `++ + a` is the correct interpretation according to the rule: "If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token." (C17 6.4 paragraph 4).

Comment: By the way, N2310 is out-of-date. I think [N3088](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3088.pdf) has the latest text of the draft standard.

Comment: ... But [N3054](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf) is nicer for the PDF bookmarks.

Comment: @IanAbbot is the numbering sequential? I have n3096 from somewhere.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. Your [N3096](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) is later. The documents are sequential, but it's not always obvious from the [WG 14 Document log](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/wg14_document_log) which documents contain the latest text of the standard. There is also N3149, but it is a password-protected zip file. N3054 and N3096 have the same general layout of "working draft". N3088 is more of a paper-like, printable version.

Comment: Specifically, since the expression is equivalent to `++ +a` according to the mentioned "maximal munch", we have post-increment and unary addition. Operator associativity of unary operators is right-to-left and so `+a` is evaluated first. The result is not a "lvalue" (addressable memory location). The requirement for ++ is that the operand must be an lvalue and so the compiler ought to whine about "lvalue required". It is not undefined behavior but rather a constraint violation of 6.5.3.1 "The operand of the prefix increment- ...  -shall be a modifiable lvalue."